# Setting a specific key (and value) depending on state of \if macro

Tags: macros, xkeyval

This question is basically a follow-up of two older questions I posted a year ago, but actually is a consequence of trying to find a solution to this
question:

[Use toggles in biblatex `printbibliography`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228293/use-toggles-in-biblatex-printbibliography)

I want to use a command with a key-value setup with an `\if` statement (pseudocode)

`\somekeycommand[\ifdisplay somekey=A \else someotherkey=B]`

such that some specific key is set according to the state of the variable `\ifdisplay`.

Unfortunately none of the various approaches work, not even the `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand....}\x` - trick is successful.

Please note, that I **don't** want to use

```
\ifdisplay
\somekeycommand[somekey=A]
\else
\somekeycommand[someotherkey=B]
\fi
```

The actual `\somekeycommand` is some code from a package, the macro uses `\setkeys`

Here is the failing MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myfam}{somekey}{%
  \def\somekeyvalue{#1}%
}

\define@key{myfam}{someotherkey}{%
  \def\somekeyothervalue{#1}%
}

\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\somekeycommand}{+O{}}{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{myfam}{#1}%
  \ifdef{\somekeyvalue}{%
    Key was \somekeyvalue%
  }{%
  }%
  \endgroup
}%

\newif\ifdisplay
\displayfalse

\begin{document}


\somekeycommand[somekey=A]



\edef\x{%
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname ifdisplay\endcsname% 
  somekey=A%
  \noexpand\else%
  someotherkey=B%
  \noexpand\fi%
}%


\somekeycommand[\x] % fails 

\somekeycommand\expandafter[\x] % fails --> expands to [ \expanded value ]

\somekeycommand[\expandafter\begingroup\edef\x{%
  \ifdisplay
 somekey=A%
\else%
someotherkey=B%
\fi%
}\x] %% -> fails, prints someotherkey=B,

\expandafter\somekeycommand[\begingroup\edef\x{%
  \noexpand\ifdisplay
  somekey=A%
  \noexpand\else%
  someotherkey=B%
  \noexpand\fi%
}\x] %% -> fails, prints someotherkey=B,



\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are the older questions of mine:

- [Generate xkeyval boolean keys 'on the fly'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152012/generate-xkeyval-boolean-keys-on-the-fly)
- [Boolean key value in xkeyval fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152020/boolean-key-value-in-xkeyval-fails)

Comment: `\setkeys` doesn't expand its second argument. I don't really understand what you're after.

Comment: @egreg: Isn't it possible at all? I wonder if it's possible to set either keyA or keyB (the key-value itself is irrelevant for now) depending whether `\ifdisplay` is evaluated to be true or to be false. The keys are different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `\setkeys` doesn't expand its second argument. I'm not sure what you're after, but this works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myfam}{somekey}{%
  \def\somekeyvalue{#1}%
}

\define@key{myfam}{someotherkey}{%
  \def\somekeyothervalue{#1}%
}

\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\somekeycommand}{+O{}}{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{myfam}{#1}%
  \ifdef{\somekeyvalue}
    {Key was \somekeyvalue}
    {\ifdef{\somekeyothervalue}{Other key was \somekeyothervalue}{}}%
  \endgroup
}%

\newif\ifdisplay
\displayfalse

\begin{document}


\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
  \somekeycommand\expandafter[\ifdisplay somekey=A\else someotherkey=B\fi]%
}\x

\displaytrue

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
  \somekeycommand\expandafter[\ifdisplay somekey=A\else someotherkey=B\fi]%
}\x


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is what I want to achieve. And I had something similar, but it failed with some complains about `\endgroup`.

Comment: Could you answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228293/use-toggles-in-biblatex-printbibliography too? ;-)